# What is the proper config in the latest Kafka for what `queue.buffering.max.ms` originally provided?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

The most recent apache Kafka docs (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation) claim "As events enter a queue, they are buffered in a queue, until either `queue.time` or `batch.size` is reached."

However, there is no `queue.time` config item present in `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig`.  The closest possible config item in the latest release of Kafka seems to be `linger.ms` which does not provide the same functionality.  The original configuration for this behavior was previously `queue.buffering.max.ms`, but this is now deprecated.

What is the proper configuration item in the latest Kafka for what `queue.buffering.max.ms` originally provided?

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This option is still there in the library [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md) so It can be set through the config.Set (key, value).

```
var config = new ProducerConfig {
  BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
  ...
}
config.Set("queue.buffering.max.ms", "5");
```